# laravel - with() loaded relations but still calling to database

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.4

I want use eager-loading to load sources of my relation so I do:
**MODEL**

```
public function files() 
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Files', 'product_files', 'product_id', 'file');
}
```

**Method**

```
Products::with(['files', 'promotion', ... etc.])->where('code', $product)->first();
```

And I have loaded relations:

```
  #relations: array:7 [▼
    "files" => Collection {#762 ▶}
    "promotion" => Collection {#755 ▶}
    ....
```

but in view still connecting to database: `500 statements were executed, 474 of which were duplicated`

**Duplicated query**

> select id from file_entries inner join product_files on file_entries.id = product_files.file where product_files.product_id = '77627'

Where is the problem?

**View**

```
                @foreach ($filesCategory as $element => $file)
                    @if (in_array($file->id, $product->files()->pluck('id')->toArray()))
                        <option selected="selected" value="{{ $file->id }}">@if( $file->name ) {{ $file->name }} @else {{ $file->oryginal_name }} @endif</option>
                    @else
                        <option value="{{ $file->id }}">@if( $file->name ) {{ $file->name }} @else {{ $file->oryginal_name }} @endif</option>
                    @endif
                @endforeach
```

Comment: What are the identical queries?

Comment: `select id from file_entries inner join product_files on file_entries.id = product_files.file where product_files.product_id = '77627'`

Comment: Can you show us how you're using the product_files data in the view?

Comment: Are there any other functions being called, mutators being used (including appends) or global scopes being used. Also, what relationship in your app does it look like this query is coming from?

Comment: Does your `File` model have a relation to an `Entry` model or similar, by any chance? It would help if you showed up _how_ you used the returned collection.

Comment: @MartinBean @ceejayoz I added my foreach which I'm using in view.
@MartinBean I don't have any relations like this, in model `Files` I have setted table `file_entries` and that's it. @Ross Wilson Nothing, only `$table`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> $product->files()->pluck('id')->toArray()
> ```

This is your problem.

`$product->files` is the eager-loaded, already fetched collection of files. That's what you're going to want to use here to benefit from eager loading. As a collection, it has the same sort of `pluck()` etc. functionality available (https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#available-methods).

`$product->files()` is a *brand-new* Eloquent query builder, so using it is going to cause a new query that's not using the eager-loaded data.